# What is the most common English term for a person who attempts a coup d'état?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, translation

In Latin America, we have the Portuguese/Spanish word *golpista* (from the word *golpe* = coup d'état). In the British media, I've read *coup monger* and also *putschist* (from German word *putsch* = coup d'état).
But are these expressions as common in English as *golpista* is for Latin Americans?

Comment: "coups d'etat" seem to be a very rare occurrence in the history of anglophone countries.  That's why the English had to adopt the French term.

Comment: I would say _plotter_ but it's going to be very difficult to source.

Comment: @Centaurus Perfidious Albion goes its own way.

Comment: @Centaurus Roger Mortimer? Henry Bolingbroke? Edward of York? Henry Tudor? -- but then Treason doth never prosper--what's the reason? Why, if it prosper, none dare call it treason.

Comment: "Dead" usually fits.

Comment: "General" works well.

Comment: Is this a single word request or not? The tag indicates so but the question is not clear on it (it suggests "coup monger" as well and seems to ask for confirmation rather than a single word)

Comment: *Puppet* is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Coup d'etater, clearly. ;)

Comment: @StoneyB - Funny, I was just going to say, “***traitor***, but only if it fails.”

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi: No, a coup de tater is when somebody swipes your chips...

Comment: @StoneyB:  The latest of those is Henry Tudor in 1485, just before the start of the existence of Latin America.  You could probably add William and Mary to that list (in 1689).  Since then I don't think there has been a proper "coup d'etat" in an Anglophone country.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The most common phrase, at least in my experience, is "coup plotter". It is, of course, not a single word.

Comment: I immediately think of 'renegade'

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes it sounds good. I'm surprised that a question that is contradictory and not clarified by its poster gets 18 upvotes here. Is the OP looking for a single word (see the tags) or just for a "common English term" (the title and body of the question)

Comment: You mean a **Guy Fawkes type** in the English experience.  See the great movie "V".

Comment: How about "rooster" -- top guy in the coup.

Comment: "Perfidious Albion goes its own way" - It certainly did revolutions its own way - as in "glorious revolution " of 1688 when members of the House or Lords wrote a letter to the Dutch king asking him if he would be so kind to visit the UK and bring an invasion force with him! The British Army then decided that if "being loyal to the monarch" involved actually fighting that was too much like hard work, so they joined the invaders instead...

Comment: @StoneyB   I meant during my lifetime, not yours. :-)

Comment: I thought I saw a coup d'etat. I did! I did see a coup d'etat!

Comment: Well, I would certainly say such a person is overly putschy.

Comment: The  tend to be called "General"

Comment: Honorary mention for "pretender": monarch who has lost the legitimacy contest (the Scottish Stuarts).

Answer (score 41):

There is no specific English agent noun for the leader or participants in the modern sense of a coup d'état, at least in common usage.

You will usually find *coup* coupled with a generic term for a leader. In fact, ***[coup leader](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/dec/05/guy-philippe-haiti-senate)*** has the most results in COCA and the BNC among all my searches. *[Coup organizer](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2014/06/16/by-ivan-perkins-the-coup-free-state/?utm_term=.f7a1f3803e87)* is roughly equivalent though much less common. In headlines or in less formal usage, *[coup chief](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-09-19/african-union-condemns-burkina-faso-coup/6788636)* or *[coup head](https://www.yahoo.com/news/burkina-faso-coup-leaders-release-interim-president-101301670.html?ref=gs)* might also be suitable.

*[Coup ringleader](https://www.thestar.com/news/world/2016/07/18/fighter-jets-patrol-skies-over-turkey-after-failed-coup.html)* and *[coup boss](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1027810/Simon-Mann-says-coup-boss-Britains-richest-men-called-The-Cardinal.html)* are dismissive and pejorative, as would be other negative words coupled with *coup*: *[plotter](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/19/world/middleeast/egypt-turkey-erdogan-coup.html)*, *[conspirator](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/7111877.stm)*, schemer, etc. You need not formulate these as attributives, either; you're more likely to read about *the orchestrator of the coup* than *the coup orchestrator*, for example.

One could make the case for *usurper* or *deposer*, but I would not say they are commonly applied to actors in a coup d'etat. A *deposer* can be one who *deposes* in the sense of removing another from power, but this sense has been largely overshadowed by the legal sense of *deposer*, one who collects a *deposition* (sworn testimony). *Usurper* in contrast is well-understood, but it carries strong connotations of the seizure of a crown (or something likened to a crown). It's unremarkable to say Henry VII was the usurper who ousted Richard III, but it's unusual to say that Nasser was the usurper who overthrow Farouk. After all, there was no longer a throne to usurp— Nasser replaced the monarchy, not just the monarch.

***[Putschist](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/putschist)***, which you have mentioned, is established, but its usage seems to be falling. Rarer still is ***[coupist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coupist)***, which can be found in a dictionary or two—

> one that attempts or supports a coup d'etat <sup>(MW)</sup>

— but little elsewhere.

[image: Google Ngram of various terms for the leader of a coup]

Comment: Comment on your ngrams - the terms would typically be used without the "coup" modifier. It's usually going to be obvious from the context.

Comment: @OrangeDog good point, but then that same qualification can apply to any context. Like ['Haddock's Eyes'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks'_Eyes), There's what you call it, what it is, how you refer to it once introduced, etc etc. Often when one asks 'What is the term for X?', it is either intended to be used entirely out of context, or at the beginning where one is setting the context (and it is not know yet).  Once context is established, 'leader', 'member' or even 'them' will do.

Comment: "coupist" uncommon, but "-ista" increasingly common, e.g. "trumpista" [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/trumpista) and the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trumpista), after Spanish "chavista". Google finds ["coupista"](http://chinogaston.blogspot.com/2006/03/pma-graduates-future-coupistas.html) followers of a "coup leader", and [here](https://phoenixwoman.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/), both wrt Latin American coups. Also [Geraldo twitter](https://twitter.com/withersteen/status/1120305201557065730), and some Spanish web pages.

Comment: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coupist) defines "coupist: one that attempts or supports a coup d'etat".  This is not the same as "coup leader". News articles such as [Greece not wanting Turkish coupists](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/reuters/article-6670845/Greece-does-not-welcome-coupists-respects-judiciarys-decisions--Greek-PM.html) and [coupistas in Mali](https://intervention.ng/21494/) and [Sierra Leone](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43658008?seq=1). Perhaps more common after 1/6/2021's events. Still, I prefer rhyming "coupista" with "trumpista".

Answer (score 31):

Assuming that by *coup d'état* you mean the sudden, usually violent overthrow of a government outside of regular political processes, ***revolutionary*** or one of its synonyms (*rebel*, *insurrectionist*, etc.) would seem most likely. From Collins Dictionaries:

> ### [revolutionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/revolutionary)
>
> *noun* ​
>   social studies **a person who supports or takes part in a
>   revolution**

---

> ### [revolution](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/revolution)
>
> *noun*
>   social studies **a sudden and great change, esp. the violent
>   change of a system of government**

The main distinguishing characteristic of a *coup* seems to be that the group of revolutionaries is relatively small and may come from within the government, and that the (attempted) overthrow is very swift. English doesn't seem to have a specific way of distinguishing either a small or an internal group of revolutionaries, although I would say that some synonyms are *less* likely to fit those parameters.

Some examples:

> In this satirical allegory, farm animals representing Bolshevik
>   **revolutionaries** successfully execute a coup d'état (which they call 'The Rebellion') —first entry [(*Animal Farm*) in Wikipedia's
>   "List of fictional revolutions and coups"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_fictional_revolutions_and_coups&oldid=744972339)
>
> A coup d'état is thus a revolution although it does not often result
>   in a dislocation within the country as always happens in the case of a
>   classic revolution. . . . [I]f the coup succeeds the constitution . . .
>   is replaced with other laws promulgated by **the revolutionaries**.
>   —[Carlson Anyangwe, *Revolutionary Overthrow of Constitutional Orders
>   in Africa*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vqEHU3iW2i0C&lpg=PA63&ots=7CM_0dPQl7&dq=revolutionaries%20coup&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q=revolutionaries%20coup&f=false) (also uses the phrase *coup-makers*)
>
> A coup launched in Berlin by a group of radical socialist
>   **revolutionaries** is brutally suppressed by right-wing paramilitary units from January 10 to January 15, 1919; the group’s leaders, Karl
>   Liebknecht and Rosa Luxemburg, are murdered. —["This Day in History",
>   The History Channel website](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/rebel-leaders-are-murdered-in-failed-coup-in-berlin)

The term ***coup-makers***, mentioned in the second example above, is sometimes used specifically for those who are most directly responsible for a coup attempt. This may be used more or less interchangeably with *revolutionaries* by some authors, but at least one source has argued that a distinction should be observed.

> Coup leaders often proclaim themselves “revolutionaries,” but coups
>   are not revolutions. . . . **Revolutionaries** seek fundamental
>   social, economic, and political change; **coup-makers** may seek this,
>   but they may act to prevent change or merely to gain the rewards of
>   political office. —["Coup d’etat." International Encyclopedia of the
>   Social Sciences](http://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/applied-and-social-sciences-magazines/coup-detat)

In practice, I believe the more general term is at least as common as any of the more specialized terms; however, it is extremely difficult to prove this, as the phrase "*the revolutionaries*" stands alone and only collocates with *coup* within the wider discussion making any automated corpus search difficult. However, *coup-makers* would be an excellent term to clarify the specific type of overthrow without a lot of context.

Comment: Which leads to the wonderfully ambiguous phrase, "the peasants are revolting"

Comment: A 'revolutionary' is way too general for a leader or member of a coup. In fact, a coup is usually _not_ revolutionary. Napoleon took power in a coup and no one would call him a revolutionary.

Comment: @Mitch too generic or not, it's very commonly used both popularly and by political scientists. The specifics generally become clear by the use of the word *coup* somewhere in the sentence or paragraph. You are correct, though, that sometimes there is a ***counter** revolutionary* coup, and this is the phrase most likely to be applied to Bonaparte. See, e.g., [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WZtM5wm-ZXQC&pg=PA310&dq=Counter-revolutionary+coup+Napoleon&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnsOHPpOfQAhVhhlQKHYvUCBsQ6AEIIDAB) or [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=AKGHDAAAQBAJ). Should I add that?

Comment: I have to say, this answer is just totally wrong.  As Mitch explained.  "revolutionary" is simply a category (like say "Dandy" or "Tall" or "Literate") which a coup-performer may belong to.

Comment: "it's very commonly used both popularly and by political scientists" give one example.  (Sure, they may then use that descriptive adjective to mention the coup'er.  But so what, you can choose an politically descriptive word - say "radical".)

Comment: @1006a 'revolutionary' is also used for non-coup leaders of revolutions.  Washington and Lenin were leaders of revolutions, but they were not part of a coup. If the OP had asked for a word for the leader of a revolution, there I would totally accept 'revolutionary' as just right.

Comment: @JoeBlow I gave three in my answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it doesn't have to be a *violent* takeover. You can have a successful one with no bloodshed.

Comment: @Mitch Absolutely, it's used for both. It's not unusual that a more general term is commonly used for a more specific thing (or vice versa—I just blew my nose on a scratchy, generic "kleenex"), because language is imprecise that way. If a more specific term is available it might be better, but even then the general term is sometimes useful, especially if the more specific term isn't known (commonly or just to the speaker) or is unwieldy. Thus the term "high heels" is often used even if "peep-toed sling-back stilettos" is more accurate.

Comment: @TylerH You're right, I've edited to clarify that.

Comment: @1006a Sure in general about general vs specific. But specifically, Napoleon was the leader of a coup, but was not revolutionary. That is why it feels wrong to use 'revolutionary' for what the OP asks.

Comment: I like the term _coup-maker_ and [according to Google](https://www.google.com/#q=%22coup-maker%22&nfpr=1) it is used.

Comment: I agree w/ Mitch that a coup is not a subset of "revolution", if we define a revolution as requiring a significant degree of popular support, and a coup as *lacking* such support -- which is why it needs to be a sudden surprise attack by a military faction; they are seizing control of existing power structures because they cannot maintain it via popular support. So there's a lot of political spin in the term (one person's revolution is another's coup), point being, in common use if you refer to something as a coup you would be unlike to refer to the leader as a "revolutionary", and vice versa.

Answer (score 21):

AN **USURPER**  is an illegitimate or controversial claimant to power, often but not always in a monarchy. This may include a person who succeeds in establishing himself as a monarch without inheriting the throne or any other person exercising authority unconstitutionally.

Usurper is a very common word and very appropriate for the leader of a coup d'etat. It can also in the plural apply to a group or a movement, but seeing as all groups tend to have a leader, Usurper makes sense in the singular as the focus of the usurpation.

The term is very established and old and is a bit antiquated for modern precise use, it's pronunciation is not the same as Georgian english, as it has vague, romantic and literary drama connotations perhaps. The Times for example may chose another term because Usurper has existed since the middle ages, and was more frequently used previous to WW2, because it still has a royalist and imperial tone of times past. It is more appropriately used for coup leaders of previous centuries, where it fits perfectly. The most current term is Coup Leader, Leader of N faction, Ex General, Warlord, Insurrectionist, Recent Accessor to power, New leader, Coup Plotter, Revolutionary, which are mostly 2-3 syllable terms and highly practical.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=usurper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cusurper%3B%2Cc0

Usurpation:
The wrongful seizure of something by force, especially of sovereignty or other authority.
Trespass onto another's property without permission.
A taking or use without right.

Comment: As a side note, I would personally write it "a usurper" rather than "an usurper" because I pronounce usurper with a long "u" at the beginning (pronounced like "you"). If you instead pronounce it with a short "u" (like the "u" in "uber") then "an usurper" is correct.

Comment: That's cool, long u for usurper sounds more attuned. I pronounce it as a french word based on Oxford pronounciation, because i haven't heard it used in conversation, have only seen it in books. In Georgian and Elizabethan times it would have sounded different and probably sounded cool, the word sounds wrong in modern received english, sounds inarticulate and doesn't sound related to politics. Just that the word contains three times the sound er and only one heard consonant, and the emphasis on the middle syllable. it's a word that has been forgotten because of it's contemporary pronounciation.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Thanks! perhaps the term coup d'etat dates from the times when Britain and America were the most involved with neo colonialist attempts around the world, and wished to pretend it was someone else, by using a French word for it.

Comment: I was thinking revolutionary for someone who attempts a coup, and usurper for someone who succeeds. Can this term apply to someone who doesn't actually succeed?

Comment: Hi, yes I think that a usurper is a claimant to power. Say that they have attempted to claim power also makes them an usurper.

Answer (score 14):

an **overthrower** is a generic term for one who causes the downfall of a ruler.

> King Charles's overthrower, Oliver Cromwell, was Lord Protector of the Commonwealth from 1653 to 1658.

[**overthrower**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overthrower) - "one who brings about the downfall, destruction, or ending of another, especially by force or concerted action"

Comment: "Overthrower" only fits if the coup is successful.

Comment: @HotLicks True. So does "coup d'état", which is called "attempted coup" otherwise. Then, "attempted overthrower" seems logical to me.

Comment: *usurper* might be a better choice.

Answer (score 13):

#### Rebel

> 1. a person who refuses allegiance to, resists, or rises in arms against the government or ruler of his or her country.

([Dictionary.con](Http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rebel))

*The rebels overthrew the government in a well-organised coup de état*

Answer (score 7):

Often "coup d'état" is shortened to just "coup". It is not common to see coup d'état in it's full form unless you are discussing a coup d'état itself.

Golpista is a good word. It is difficult to find a direct and meaningful translation for this.

"participant in a coup" would be the most literal and direct translation. However, this phrase is so generic that most people do not normally say this.

Every coup d'état has an ideology or methodology behind it. Generally you pick a either the ideology or the methodology to describe these participants.

If you describe participants based on ideology you could call them "militants" or "nationalists" or "anarchists" or "communists". The coup itself would then be a "military coup", or a "nationalist coup", or "anarchist coup" or a "communist coup."

If you describe the participants by methodology you could say they were "extremists" or "terrorists" or "pacifists". The coup itself would then be an "extremist coup" or "terrorist coup" or "pacifist coup".

In Spanish there are words for all of these things already: "militantes, nacionalistas, anarquistas, comunistas, extremistas, terroristas, pacifistas"

So for working English, just pick the kind of golpista they are.

Comment: Good point that *golpista* itself could be borrowed. After all, that's how we got *caudillo* and *junta*, too. The Oxford translation dictionary's suggestions are, at best, [clumsy](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/spanish-english/golpista)

Comment: It's worth noting that a lot of these terms depend on which side of the conflict you are on (Revolutionaries may describe themselves as pacifists while the state media may refer to them as terrorists, what might be called a "communist rebellion" in the US might be called a "socialist rebellion" in Europe, especially during the Cold War).

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the wikipedia page for the [recent Turkish coup attempts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Turkish_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat_attempt), there isn't one agreed upon term, with different contributors/sources using different words. The most common one seems to be *plotter* though. Here's the frequency as of today:

> Plotter(s)- 23
>
> Rebels- 7
>
> Coupist(s)- 7
>
> Coup leader(s)- 4
>
> Putschist(s)- 6
>
> Conspirators- 2

Comment: Today, 13 December 2016, the word _conspirators_ is on the front page of the English-language Wikipedia, see [Wikipedia:Selected anniversaries/December 13 (permanent link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Selected_anniversaries/December_13&oldid=754577493). The context is: _"With Emperor of Ethiopia Haile Selassie (pictured) out of the country, four conspirators staged a coup attempt and installed Crown Prince Asfaw Wossen as the new Emperor."_

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context, ***[mutineer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutinies)*** could also apply:

> - one that mutinies

[M-W.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutineer)

***[Mutinies](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutinies)***:

> - forcible or passive resistance to lawful authority; especially :  concerted revolt (as of a naval crew) against discipline or a superior officer

[M-W.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutinies)

Answer (score 3):

You may consider also ***[subversive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/subversive)***:

> - a person who adopts subversive principles or policies.
> - (Also, subversionary) tending or intending to subvert or overthrow, destroy, or undermine an established or existing system, especially a legally constituted government or a set of beliefs.
>     noun

Dictionary.co

From [Paraguay and the United States: Distant Allies](https://books.google.it/books?id=mFEY_Ingg88C&pg=PA160&dq=%22subversives%20were%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJmPflzObQAhUJBMAKHUz-CGs4ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22subversives%20were%22&f=false):

> - In fact, the spokespeople of the dictatorship continued to insist that ***Cuban-oriented subversives were busily attempting to destabilize the country.***!As the regime conducted several successful mopping up operations in the countryside between 1961 and 1963, it attempted to win favor with the new administration in Washington.

Comment: *Subversive* is quite a bit broader than the people who attempt a coup, however— journalists, or business elites, or the professoriat, or drug lords, or any number of other elements of society could act as *subversives* trying to undermine the government or other institutions without ever using or threatening force.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the term *Junta*

> a military or political group that rules a country after taking power by force.

If the Junta is successful the leader might be called *Generalissimo* (e.g. Generalissimo Franco)

Answer (score 2):

The Spanish word *golpe* is a very convenient word as it can have various meanings including coup d'état. The English equivalent should be "couper" or "coupist" and the word "coupist" is listed in some dictionaries.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coupist):

> One who takes part in a coup d'état

[Collins Online Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/17625/coupist):

> a leader or a participant in a coup d'état

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coupist):

> one that attempts or supports a coup d'etat

This word is not broadly used in English and *a participant in coup (or coup d'état)* will be a more appropriate term.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no one mentioned Insurrectionist.  Listed under insurrection as a related noun.

`in·sur·rec·tion  (ĭn′sə-rĕk′shən) n.
The act or an instance of open revolt against civil authority or a constituted government.`

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/insurrectionist

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on win/lose/draw. Win; Despot? Dictator? Emperor? Head Congressional Clown? No, wait, that would be here. Lose; Dead. Draw; Ambassador or Envoy to some place where many horrid things happen hourly.